# Rigidbody двигает объект вниз при положительной силе

Tags: c#, unity3d, физика

Рассчитываю силу по формуле Масса * ускорение, при положительном ускорение меньше чем 10 объект идет вниз,при ускорение 10 и больше объект только начинает подниматься. Собственно вопрос как работает Rigidbody вместе с массой и силой ?

Суть в том что необходимо реализовать физику поведения самолета по оси Y.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    float countTurn = control.GetCountTurn();
    speedPlane = countTurn * speedInTurn;

    float currentBoost = 10f;

    /*
    if (control.isMaxAngle())
    {
        currentBoost += 0.5f;
    }
    else
    {
        currentBoost += control.GetDiffLastAngle() * speedInTurn;
    }*/

    //currentBoost *= 10;

    float currentForce = rigidbody.mass * currentBoost;

    Debug.Log("FORCCE " + currentForce + " " + rigidbody.velocity.magnitude);

    rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector3(0,currentForce), ForceMode.Force);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще говоря, при `isGravity == true` на объекты действует гравитация или, другими словами в контексте физики Unity, **сила тяжести**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ускорение свободного падения `g = 9.81 ~ 10`. Чтобы объект **хотя бы не падал**, вам нужно прикладывать к нему силу `>= 9.81 * 3500`, т.е. значение переменной `currentBoost` должно быть больше либо равно `g = 9.81`.